# Are there any Flex libraries that support image editing?

Tags: apache-flex, image-editor

I'm looking for something that will support image rotation, multiple image layers, cropping, etc., and allow the client to customize which features are to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

The following link contains some examples.
http://ntt.cc/2010/08/20/20-coolest-adobe-air-apps.html

Please scroll down to number 16 and 17 on the page.